# How can I define whether a number is square number or not in C?

Tags: c

How can I define whether a number is square or not in C language? Such as to find square root of any positive integer we use `sqrt()` function in C language which is written in `<math.h>` header file.

Suppose we have to find the square root of positive integer x. The program will be in C language.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
  int x;
  double sq;

  scanf("%d", &x);    
  sq = sqrt(x);    
  printf("%0.2f\n", sq);

  return 0;
}
```

Like this, so now what will be the best approach to find whether a number is square number or not?

Comment: Do you want to verify the result of `sqrt`? Please clarify your question. What number is "a number"?

Comment: The number could be any positive integer number such as 1,2,3,4,100,34,..... and the program will define if the number is square number or not. and i gave the program to find a number's square root value as an example that we use sqrt function to find the square root value of any number but what will we use if we want to find whether a number is square number or not ?

Comment: did you try `if (x == (int)sq * (int)sq)`?

Comment: `int(sq) * int(sq) == x` ?

Comment: Theoretically, every number is a squared number. Because sqrt(x) *sqrt(x) =x =

Comment: @Raildex: not true - no negative number is a squared number.

Comment: Yes,  but OP meant positive integers

Comment: Ah - didn't see that.  Fair enough :)

Comment: It's true if we use complex numbers

Comment: @Mr.E Also true - though that's a separate function not necessarily available in C.  `sqrt` in `math.h` will return an error if you try to take the square root of a negative number.

Comment: @Raildex Pigeon hole principle: `sqrt(x) *sqrt(x) == x` is not always true with positive `double`.  Consider the `n` different `double` in `1 <= x < 4`.  They map to `N/2` `double` of `1<= sqrt(x) < 2`.  Squaring that result results in `N/2` different `double`.  So half the possible `x` are not properly compared.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    double x;

    double sq;

    scanf("%lf",&x);

    sq = sqrt(x); 

    if( sq == (int)sq )
        printf("sq is a root\n");
    else
        printf("sq is not a root\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what happens if `sq` is for example `703.00000000000001`, casting to int returns `703` and the implicit cast to double returns `703.000000000000001` (one `0` more)?

Comment: Your argument would be more persuasive if you used examples that were the square root of an integer.

Comment: I checked the first 100000000 square roots for a series of four zeros following the decimal and found about 5000 of them. I did it again for a series of 5 zeros and found none. So, it's safe to use this for numbers within the range of 1-100000000 at least.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the square root, cast the result to an `int`, which will truncate any fractional component.  Then multiply that number by itself, and check to see if it equals the original number.

```
int x = // some nonnegative number
double sq = sqrt(x);
int sq_int = (int)sq;
if (sq_int * sq_int == x) {
    print("%d is a square\n", x);
} else {
    print("%d is not a square\n", x);
}
```

For example, if `x` is 9, then `sq` is 3.0.  So `sq_int` is set to 3, and since `3 * 3 == 9` is true, it prints `9 is a square`.

If `x` is 10, then `sq` is 3.162277....  So `sq_int` is set to 3 (since the fractional part is truncated), and since `3 * 3 == 10` is false, it prints `10 is not a square`.